# symfony collection type form field with linking to existing object and allowing new objects

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Dont know how this field is called correctly

But is there a simple way to add collection type field with an option to select existing records and posibility to add new records and delete records from entity?

Basically a want to have a post entity with tags linked to it
In admin interface when creating or editing post i want a posibility to add existing tags to post and also new tags

i've tried this article https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html
but there is no option to add from existing records

could you advise me how to implement this?
or how this field is called correctly?
or maybe there is some extension for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign multiple entities to another entity with Symfony form, I think the best way to do this is to use `EntityType` field with multiple option enabled. For better styling I prefer to use Select2 library.

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox

Comment: And adding tags just requires another form with an input field and a button which you could place in a modal box like this bootstrap example https://codepen.io/frankbeen/pen/qBdrZvy